# Javascript click event before MVC Action call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What I have written works and am looking for more understanding when it comes to events fired from javascript vs events fired to an MVC Action. The javascript I have sets a value true or false based on the button that is pressed. Is the form pended or is it not pended is the user actions. At the same instance (I believe) the button press submits the form to my controller.

Here is what I am describing. Just below is the form I submit on the button clicks.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RejectInsertComment", Model.controller, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "modal-form" }))
{
    <!-- form elements -->
            ....
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.is_pended)
    <input type="submit" class="PendLink btn btn-primary" name="Pend" value="Pend"/>
    <input type="submit" class="CompleteLink btn btn-primary" name="Complete" value="Complete" />
}
```

Then here is the javascript, toggling the value of pend.

```
 $('.PendLink').click(function () {
            $('#is_pended').val(true);
        });
 $('.CompleteLink').click(function () {
            $('#is_pended').val(false);
        });
```

This works, and I assume the Javascript fires first on the client, but how does MVC know to wait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, ASP.NET MVC does not really have events, the form is simply submitted to the action url that is provided; this has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC. Almost always javascript will successfully execute before the form submits (depending how fast the javascript at hand can run). If you really want to ensure javascript runs before the form is submitted, you need to use a method like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return mySubmitFunction()">
  ...
</form>
<script>
function mySubmitFunction(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  someBug();
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting. Although, that makes sense. If I had more complicated JS going on maybe I should use the preventDefault method. Would you suggest I do this with the click event?

Comment: Updated: This is one way to do it if you don't want to submit the form and only run a js function. If you want to do both with JS running first, you can use a regular button instead of a submit button and do $("#yourFormId").submit(); at the end of your js function.

Answer (score 1):

You got it wrong, there is no MVC once your browser gets the response from server. MVC is only server side. All your `.cshtml` files are converted into plain `HTML` and sent back as response.

So this code of yours `@using (Html.BeginForm(..` will be changed into a HTML `form` tag.

So in reality you are dealing only with HTML on client side.

So now coming to the part of Jquery executing before form submit. Yes, when ever you have events binded to your DOM (click event in this case) the events are executed one after the other. So in your `click` handler If you don't stop the event (eg: `e.preventDefault()`)  then as a next event the form will be submitted.